# Problems setting range with Office Javascript from Excel Online Add-In

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I am trying set a range of cells an Excel Add-In.

```
var officeInitialized = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Office.initialize = () => {
        resolve();
        };
    });

function setValues(parms) {
    return Excel.run((ctx) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < parms.ranges.length; i++) {
            var addr = parms.ranges[i];
            var addrPart = addr.split("!");
            var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(addrPart[0]);
            if (sheet == null) {
                sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.add(addrPart[0]);
                sheet.activate();
            }
            var range = sheet.getRange(addrPart[1]);
            range.values = parms.values[i];
        }
        return ctx.sync()
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                return {};
            });
    });
}

function Test() {
    console.log("Test called");
    setValues({ranges: ["Tabelle1!A1:B2"], "values":[[[1, 2],[3, 4]]]});
}
```

My function is called. But the range content does not change. The error handler is not called.

What's wrong?

Comment: I just have a try with your sample code, it runs as expected on both Excel online and Mac. the range values are corrected set, what's the output in the console window?

Comment: "Test called" is output on each call to Test() (a simple button)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/c8bbc5792c5059f85d4cdd944a13d4b6, this is the gist that i am using, can you try it on other platform as well? eg: Windows or Mac?

Comment: I am using  browser based Excel though Google Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I just verifed on my Windows Desktop Excel, it also works as expected. so could you try to import my gist and validate on your Windows desktop Excel as well?

Comment: I tried your Gist (ie I took the Javascript code (replacing the Jquery code with a direct call from the button). It is called, but the Excel sheet is not modified.

Comment: Are you using script lab to run this gist?

Comment: No, I just found out that Script Lab exists now. I first put my code on my web server (together with other functions) and used Office 365. Later I copied your Javascript on my web server (including everythng in a simple HTML file) and used Office 365. Your code works from Script Lab but not from the HTML page.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the setting in 2 levels of Excel.run?